# Adding HTML text and render it as HTML only in display template

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

I have created an list with Multiline text column. I am adding some text and some HTML.
Once I read the value from text in angular js, and print it on screen, the HTML block written in the column is also rendered as text and not HTML.

How can I achieve this?

For reference:
Value inside multiline column is :

```
This is the video 
<video src=""></video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Angular's `ng-bind-html` directive.

In the html, it would be something like : `<span ng-bind-html="item.Description"></span>`

In your controller, you need to set the value of description as below:

```
Description: $sce.trustAsHtml(data.Description)
```

In your controller, also ensure that `$sce` is present as below:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    // ... [your code]
 }]);
```

Reference - [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

[$sce - Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

[use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342738/862892)